# Charts hide LineMark?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-charts

I just started working with Charts in SwiftUI and there is one thing I can't figure out, if it's even possible to achieve. Let's say my Y axis ranges from 0 to 1. If I have a value that is -1, is it possible to only hide that one LineMark without shifting the whole graph? Does this make sense?

Another example is an array like this [0.5, 0.2, -1, -1, 0.9, 0.7]. Is it possible to ignore index 2 and 3 and then pick up again at index 4?

To ignore indexes out of range and then pick up from the next index on the X axis